# Back Button in webView

Tags: android-activity, android-fragments, android, android-menu

When the user clicks on back button, I've implemented the following code that works very well for links inside of my webview:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (this.webViewFragment != null && this.webViewFragment.canGoBack()) {
        this.webViewFragment.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

My problem is that I have native menu in Android, and when the user clicks on the menu Profile for example and then clicks on the menu Dashboard, the back button doesn't work. Nothing happens. As I said before, just works for links clicked inside of the webview.

Anyone knows a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

or try this

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: This is the same :P .. The only difference is that it works for old versions too..